# Bad smell from disherwasher - is this a bad setup?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

I've been noticing a bad sewer-like smell that happens when I run the dish washer. The house is older, and the setup under the kitchen sink is a bit confusing. There was once a garbage disposal, but it was removed. The Torani bottle you can see in the picture is full after the dishwasher runs.

[image: Under sink]

My first thought is that I need to clean the trap, and the second is that the black hose should either be higher than the drain from the sink. But the whole setup seems weird. Is something wrong the setup?

Comment: What is the purpose of all the black pipe? Why doesn't the dishwasher just feed straight into the white tailpiece which the black pipe is connected to?

Comment: I have no idea. We are still fairly new to the house, and the previous owners had some....interesting setups. You should see some of the wiring :(

Comment: you have another problem with all that extra water on the floor; mildew. come to think of it, that might be the source of the smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the pipe from the dishwasher does not have a high point before its connection to the sink drain. So water flows from the sink into the dishwasher drain pipe and sits there. All you need to do is clamp the dishwasher drain pipe to near the top of the cabinet right before the connection with the sink drain.

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight

Comment: This seems to have reduced the problem. I may still end up sealing it up just in case the sink gets full of water and drains out.